# What if I call CloseHandle(h) before an asynchronous read on handle h has not finished?

Tags: c, windows, exception, file-io, asynchronous

Consider the following scenario:

```
auto h = CreateFile(...);
ReadFileEx(h, ...); // Asynchronous read for a large block of data. say, 1GB.
CloseHandle(h); 
// If the read has not yet finished here, what will happen? Big Bang???
```

Comment: @Alok, could you refer me to the specific MSDN page?

Comment: If you can, try using the file management functions described in the C89 standard, http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen and http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose

Comment: Also, you could tell the OS to do the asynchronous read for you by using mmap, and mapping the file to memory directly. (For some pointers, see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/mmap-tutorial-c-c-511265/)

Comment: @xmllmx: It is my best guess. I could not find any reference which specifically says so.

Comment: What's the motivation for engaging in such risky behavior? Isn't that precisely why the last parameter to the `ReadFileEx` function lets you specify a pointer to a function that is called when the operation completes? Call `CloseHandle` there.

Comment: @AlokSave if its any consolation, that only further solidifies the strength of the "undefined" in "undefined behavior" regarding this question. =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as the Asyncronous handle was valid at the time of the call, the asynchronous operation will remain valid until it completes. This is because Asyncronous file IO calls hold an implicit reference count to the file object in the kernel.

When the asyncronous event completes, if there are no more handles in usermode pointing to the file, the file will be closed internally in the kernel.

Note that this does have visible side-effects. In particular, if you have the file open for exclusive read/write, issue an async operation and then close the handle, the file will not be available to be opened for read/write until the async operation completes.

Comment: I just measured the issue: I wrote some code, first a CancelIo to cancel all outstanding I/O-operations then a CloseHandle. The CancelIo lasts about 15ms - measured with GetSystemTimeAsFiletime -, the CloseHandle afterwards wasnt measurable exactly, i.e. it took 0ms. When I removed the CancelIo CloseHandle had 15ms CPU-time. So it looks like CloseHandle implicitly cancels oustanding I/O-requests.